# How to make non-greedy regular expression? "?" does not seem to work

Tags: java, regex

Here is the content of html:

```
<span style=\"color:red;\">\u7eaa\u51ef\u5a77<\/span>\uff0c\u6709\u6700<span style=\"color:red;\">
```

and I try to match the first `<span style=\"color:red;\">`, but when my pattern is

```
Pattern.compile("<span .+?style=\\\\\"color:red;\\\\\">");
```

I will get the all sentence instead of the first one.

What should I do?

Comment: First:  what are you actually trying to capture?

Comment: i try to capture <span style=\"color:red";\">

Comment: .+? means one ore more of any character, which will be as non-greedy as it can until it sees the last instance of style. What you want more likely is a non-greedy operator after the word 'style', rather than before it. Also, why are you using .+ to match whitespace? Use \s instead.

Comment: And second: are these backslashes really in your html, or are you showing a java or javascript string that contains your html? there are an awful lot of backslashes in your regex and it doesn't seem logical to have backslashes in your actual html.

Comment: I'm assuming the to-search string is escaped properly, because the regex he's posted does capture it: Java string is `\\\\\"` --> regex is `\\"`.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the final question mark in the regex. If the final double-quote is optional, shouldn't its escape-slash also be optional? Meaning `(?:\\")?`

Comment: You should mark his answer as accepted then.

Comment: I do try match the html using Java, so there are so many backlashes.

Comment: Additionally, it's nearly always a bad idea to try to use regular expressions on HTML; use a parser such as JSoup instead.

Comment: i am a new user, can you tell me how to mark the Ryan J provided as accepted?

Comment: @aliteralmind, i just try to let the regex stop at the ">". I have a misunderstanding about the usage of "?". Actually, no need to have the final question mark.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your requirements, your problem is that your regex

```
<span .+?style=\\\\\"color:red;\\\\\"?>
```

requires *one or more characters* between the space and the word "style" This makes it impossible to capture the first tag, as I believe is your goal. Greedy and possessive and reluctant doesn't matter in this case.

It should likely something more like this:

```
<span\s+style=\\"color:red;\\">
```

Comment: your regex cannot match the sentence: <span style=\"color:red;\">

Comment: Updated. I eliminated the final question mark as well. I don't understand its purpose.

Comment: Your edits incorporated what I intended to convey. I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @RyanJ: Thanks. I actually find it odd to accept tabs and newlines and linefeeds and so on between `span` and `style`, but I understand it's more generically useful to do so.

Comment: Given we don't know the nature of the HTML being captured, I figured we'd err on the side of caution rather than holding true to style brevity. Thanks.